# Docker-compose up -d:image not created

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a basic web page with docker-compose
This is my yml file

```
identidock:
  build: . 
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  environment:
    ENV: DEV 
  volumes:
    - ./app:/app
```

When I run

```
docker-compose up -d
```

it shows

```
Starting identidock_identidock_1 ... done
```

But if I check images
 docker images

```
REPOSITORY                                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
identidock_identidock                      latest              b5003205377f        12 days ago         698MB
identidock                                 latest              8eafce868d95        12 days ago         698MB
<none>                                     <none>              de77d0555129        13 days ago         698MB
<none>                                     <none>              2f8bfc8f0a95        13 days ago         697MB
<none>                                     <none>              a42d37d82f28        2 weeks ago         535MB
<none>                                     <none>              592d8c832533        2 weeks ago         695MB
python                                     3.4                 41f9e544ec6c        2 weeks ago         684MB
```

It is obvious that new image has not been created.If I to http://localhost:5000/,
I got
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:5000.

This is docker ps -a output

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                        NAMES
0414117eadd8        identidock_identidock                      "/cmd.sh"                12 days ago         Exited (255) 11 days ago    9090/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, 9191/tcp   blissful_easley
4146fd976547        identidock_identidock:latest               "/cmd.sh"                12 days ago         Exited (255) 11 days ago    9090/tcp, 9191/tcp                           agitated_leakey
15d49655b290        identidock_identidock                      "/cmd.sh"                12 days ago         Exited (1) 23 minutes ago                                                identidock_identidock_1
```

And

```
docker-compose ps
         Name             Command   State    Ports
--------------------------------------------------
identidock_identidock_1   /cmd.sh   Exit 1
```

Why?

Comment: try running docker ps -a and show us the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container may not have started. Check `docker-compose ps`. If the containers listed are not in *Up* state, then you can use `docker-compose logs identidock` to view the logs.

Comment: It means that an error occurred when the container started. You can diagnose further by looking at the container logs.